# How to copy a file upon delete using .NET / C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How can .NET (C# or VB.NET) be used to create a copy of a file whenever it is deleted from the file system?  We have laptop users who regularly delete files without knowing when/if they have been backed up.  I would like to build a Windows service to watch for delete events and copy the file to a safe location prior to the file actually being deleted.  My searches have pointed me to the recycling bin, however I cannot guarantee that the Recycle Bin is in use.

Comment: I think this is already done in Windows 8 with the new file history feature.

Comment: You probably could use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Bartosz no, `FileSystemWatcher.Deleted` fires after the file is gone, which makes it hard to copy. ;-) OP: this really sounds like you should either educate your users or configure backup on the machine.

Comment: This is not impossible, you just picked a lousy choice of language.  Writing a file system filter driver still requires using C or C++.  And a few more black-belt skills.  Or a simple credit card, this has been done before of course.

Comment: @HansPassant I think the search phrase for that is "continuous data protection"?

Comment: This user is irresponsible. You should take an administrative action against him/her because they can harm your business. He/she can change the contents of the file in a wrong way too.

Comment: @HansPassant: Do you know of a component that I could integrate with a .NET app?

Answer (score 2):

To intercept a deletion before it happens, you'll need to write a [**file system minifilter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540402(v=vs.85).aspx), which is pretty much by definition not managed code.  However, it can be an otherwise fairly thin component that can [talk to a service or application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539277(v=vs.85).aspx), which can itself be written in managed code with a side order of P/Invoke.

Be careful not to filter deletions of files created (or discarded as too old/already backed up) by your service.  The managed code framework itself sometimes uses temporary files as well; XmlSerializer likes to compile temporary assemblies to accelerate its operation.  Fail to exercise due care and your code may go all [ouroboros](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-syFlmX-h1LQ/T1_7fxh5V9I/AAAAAAAAEwU/u4BFB34ZC8w/s400/600px-Ouroboros-simple.svg.png).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realise the Resident Evil 5 virus "Uroburos" was based on anything.. :) Good advice though!